# Rails 4.2: image path and fingerprint only added when config.assets.compile = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

In production, the correct paths to my images are not called with the image tag, and the md5 fingerprint is not added. The image names (e.g. "pretty_picture.jpg") are stored in the database. The precompilation files are all present in the public folder including the manifest file.

When called with image_tag:

```
image_tag @test_question.question.image
```

I get:

```
<img src="/images/pretty_picture.jpg">
```

If I set config.assets.compile = true in production.rb  the image is rendered and I get:

```
<img src="/assets/images/pics/pretty/pretty_picture-e0df5012b6930cda4efaa866af22a63f.jpg" >
```

My hack solution is to use (in HAML)

```
%img{src: "/assets/"+Rails.application.assets.find_asset(@test_question.question.image).digest_path}
```

In production.rb I have

```
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.enabled = true
config.serve_static_files = false
config.assets.compile = false
```

Setting the config.assets.compile to true in production is not recommended. This seems like very strange behaviour on behalf of sprockets and the asset pipeline. Any idea what is wrong with the use of image_tag here?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - thanks for finding that hack solution - it at least get's me some working code.

Comment: Has there been a non-hack solution to this problem?  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In production, you should precompile the assets before starting the server, with the following command (and automate it to do it every time you deploy):

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV="production"
```

and keep `config.assets.compile = false` in your `production.rb`. Check in the [Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production).

Comment: Yes, the assets are precompiled for the correct environment and deployed with Capistrano to the server. As stated in the question stem, the assets are present in the public folder as they should be, and config.assets.compile = false. The images are not referenced correctly in the view.